# ¿ como puedo saber cuando una ventana esta abierta?

Tags: python, tkinter

El código que tengo es muy grande para ponerlo acá, pero supongamos que tengo una simple ventana que si presiono un botón abre otra ventana, ¿ como podría yo saber si la ventana esta abierta ? pregunto esto por que si vuelvo a presionar el botón se abriría otra ventana mas y así sucesivamente, entonces quiero saber como puedo abrir solo una ventana y cuando cierro la ventana pueda volver abrirla, se que puedo desactivar el botón pero no me sirve esa solución ya que necesito que el botón siempre este habilitado.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def n_ventana():
   root2 = Tk()


Button(root, text="Nueva Ventana", command=n_ventana).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que este código sirva, perdón si mi explicación no es detallada.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def n_ventana():
    #Reviso si la ventana está abierta
    #En caso de que la ventana esté abierta, no se abre otra.
    if(n_ventana.opened):
        return
    
    n_ventana.opened = True
    
    root2 = Tk()

    #Espero a que la ventana se cierre
    root2.wait_window()
    n_ventana.opened = False

#Establezco el valor inicial de n_ventana.opened.
#Como la ventana no estará abierta, le pondré False
n_ventana.opened = False

Button(root, text="Nueva Ventana", command=n_ventana).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Excelente me funciono el código, la explicación no es tan clara pero todo bien.